# Why argsort instead of argmin here?

Tags: python, numpy

Looking at this exercise from http://scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/exercises.html#array-manipulations:

> Harder one: Generate a 10 x 3 array of random numbers (in range [0,1]). For each row, pick the number closest to 0.5.
>
> - Use abs and argsort to find the column j closest for each row.
> - Use fancy indexing to extract the numbers. (Hint: a[i,j] – the array i must contain the row numbers corresponding to stuff in j.)

I've solved it like this:

```
a = numpy.random.random((10, 3))
b = numpy.abs(a - 0.5)
b = b.argmin(axis=1)
b = a[numpy.arange(len(b)), b]
```

Except doing:

```
b = numpy.argsort(b)[:, 0]
```

how can `argsort` be used in a better way than `argmin`?

Comment: Using `argsort` is clearly less efficient than `argmin`. I think the writer or the exercises just missed this better solution. This is actually very frequent for people to use sort instead of min-max or partition algorithms. This is very sad since sorting is expensive.

Comment: I agree with @JérômeRichard. Just because you see it in a course or even on SO doesn't mean it is the best way to do something.

Comment: Im sure author meant `argmin`, but wrote `argsort` by mistake. Sidenote: sorting is sometimes useful - its easier (faster) to find an item or an item closest to some value in a sorted array . So if you have a lot of such searches to be done it may be more efficient to first sort the array and then use this sorted array to perform those searches.

Comment: You could create an issue about this in the [github repo](https://github.com/scipy-lectures/scipy-lecture-notes).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser https://github.com/scipy-lectures/scipy-lecture-notes/issues/611